# Check your gas amount error ERC721

Tags: solidity, ganache

I am trying to deploy contracts to Ganache for testing using Truffle, but no matter what I set gas price / gas limit / gas to both in truffle.js and Ganache itself, it always get check gas amount on the first contract and it errors out. If you need more info let me know

Here is the contract to deploy:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

import "../CheckERC165.sol";
import "../standard/ERC721.sol";
import "../standard/ERC721TokenReceiver.sol";
import "../libraries/SafeMath.sol";

/// @title A scalable implementation of the ERC721 NFT standard
/// @author Andrew Parker
contract TokenERC721 is ERC721, CheckERC165{
    using SafeMath for uint256;


    //Tokens with owners of 0x0 revert to contract creator, makes the contract scalable.
    address internal creator;
    //maxId is used to check if a tokenId is valid.
    uint256 internal maxId;
    mapping(address => uint256) internal balances;
    mapping(uint256 => bool) internal burned;
    mapping(uint256 => address) internal owners;
    mapping (uint256 => address) internal allowance;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => bool)) internal authorised;


    /// @notice Contract constructor
    /// @param _initialSupply The number of tokens to mint initially
    constructor(uint _initialSupply) public CheckERC165(){
        creator = msg.sender;
        balances[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        maxId = _initialSupply;

        //Add to ERC165 Interface Check
        supportedInterfaces[
            this.balanceOf.selector ^
            this.ownerOf.selector ^
            //this.safeTransferFrom.selector ^
            //Have to manually do the two transferFroms because overloading confuse selector
            bytes4(keccak256("safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256"))^
            bytes4(keccak256("safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256,bytes"))^
            this.transferFrom.selector ^
            this.approve.selector ^
            this.setApprovalForAll.selector ^
            this.getApproved.selector ^
            this.isApprovedForAll.selector
        ] = true;
    }

    /// @notice Checks if a given tokenId is valid
    /// @dev If adding the ability to burn tokens, this function will need to reflect that.
    /// @param _tokenId The tokenId to check
    /// @return (bool) True if valid, False if not valid.
    function isValidToken(uint256 _tokenId) internal view returns(bool){
        return _tokenId != 0 && _tokenId <= maxId && !burned[_tokenId];
    }


    /// @notice Count all NFTs assigned to an owner
    /// @dev NFTs assigned to the zero address are considered invalid, and this
    ///  function throws for queries about the zero address.
    /// @param _owner An address for whom to query the balance
    /// @return The number of NFTs owned by `_owner`, possibly zero
    function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint256){
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    /// @notice Find the owner of an NFT
    /// @param _tokenId The identifier for an NFT
    /// @dev NFTs assigned to zero address are considered invalid, and queries
    ///  about them do throw.
    /// @return The address of the owner of the NFT
    function ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns(address){
        require(isValidToken(_tokenId));
        if(owners[_tokenId] != 0x0 ){
            return owners[_tokenId];
        }else{
            return creator;
        }
    }

    /// @notice Mints more tokens, can only be called by contract creator and
    /// all newly minted tokens will belong to creator.
    /// @dev This function is optional, it isn't required by the ERC721 spec,
    /// and is not needed if the initial supply of NFTs is all that is needed.
    /// @dev Throws if msg.sender isn't creator, or if added tokens overflows maxId (uint256)
    /// @param _extraTokens The number of extra tokens to mint.
    function issueTokens(uint256 _extraTokens) public{
        require(msg.sender == creator);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(_extraTokens);

        //We have to emit an event for each token that gets created
        for(uint i = maxId.add(1); i <= maxId.add(_extraTokens); i++){
            emit Transfer(0x0, creator, i);
        }

        maxId += _extraTokens; //<- SafeMath for this operation was done in for loop above
    }

    function burnToken(uint256 _tokenId) external{
        address owner = ownerOf(_tokenId);
        require ( owner == msg.sender             //Require sender owns token
            //Doing the two below manually instead of referring to the external methods saves gas
            || allowance[_tokenId] == msg.sender      //or is approved for this token
            || authorised[owner][msg.sender]          //or is approved for all
        );
        burned[_tokenId] = true;
        balances[owner]--;

        //Have to emit an event when a token is burnt
        emit Transfer(owner, 0x0, _tokenId);
    }


    /// @notice Set or reaffirm the approved address for an NFT
    /// @dev The zero address indicates there is no approved address.
    /// @dev Throws unless `msg.sender` is the current NFT owner, or an authorized
    ///  operator of the current owner.
    /// @param _approved The new approved NFT controller
    /// @param _tokenId The NFT to approve
    function approve(address _approved, uint256 _tokenId)  external{
        address owner = ownerOf(_tokenId);
        require( owner == msg.sender                    //Require Sender Owns Token
            || authorised[owner][msg.sender]                //  or is approved for all.
        );
        emit Approval(owner, _approved, _tokenId);
        allowance[_tokenId] = _approved;
    }

    /// @notice Get the approved address for a single NFT
    /// @dev Throws if `_tokenId` is not a valid NFT
    /// @param _tokenId The NFT to find the approved address for
    /// @return The approved address for this NFT, or the zero address if there is none
    function getApproved(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address) {
        require(isValidToken(_tokenId));
        return allowance[_tokenId];
    }

    /// @notice Query if an address is an authorized operator for another address
    /// @param _owner The address that owns the NFTs
    /// @param _operator The address that acts on behalf of the owner
    /// @return True if `_operator` is an approved operator for `_owner`, false otherwise
    function isApprovedForAll(address _owner, address _operator) external view returns (bool) {
        return authorised[_owner][_operator];
    }




    /// @notice Enable or disable approval for a third party ("operator") to manage
    ///  all your assets.
    /// @dev Emits the ApprovalForAll event
    /// @param _operator Address to add to the set of authorized operators.
    /// @param _approved True if the operators is approved, false to revoke approval
    function setApprovalForAll(address _operator, bool _approved) external {
        emit ApprovalForAll(msg.sender,_operator, _approved);
        authorised[msg.sender][_operator] = _approved;
    }


    /// @notice Transfer ownership of an NFT -- THE CALLER IS RESPONSIBLE
    ///  TO CONFIRM THAT `_to` IS CAPABLE OF RECEIVING NFTS OR ELSE
    ///  THEY MAY BE PERMANENTLY LOST
    /// @dev Throws unless `msg.sender` is the current owner, an authorized
    ///  operator, or the approved address for this NFT. Throws if `_from` is
    ///  not the current owner. Throws if `_to` is the zero address. Throws if
    ///  `_tokenId` is not a valid NFT.
    /// @param _from The current owner of the NFT
    /// @param _to The new owner
    /// @param _tokenId The NFT to transfer
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public {
        //Check Transferable
        //There is a token validity check in ownerOf
        address owner = ownerOf(_tokenId);

        require ( owner == msg.sender             //Require sender owns token
            //Doing the two below manually instead of referring to the external methods saves gas
            || allowance[_tokenId] == msg.sender      //or is approved for this token
            || authorised[owner][msg.sender]          //or is approved for all
        );
        require(owner == _from);
        require(_to != 0x0);
        //require(isValidToken(_tokenId)); <-- done by ownerOf

        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _tokenId);

        owners[_tokenId] = _to;
        balances[_from]--;
        balances[_to]++;
        //Reset approved if there is one
        if(allowance[_tokenId] != 0x0){
            delete allowance[_tokenId];
        }
    }

    /// @notice Transfers the ownership of an NFT from one address to another address
    /// @dev Throws unless `msg.sender` is the current owner, an authorized
    ///  operator, or the approved address for this NFT. Throws if `_from` is
    ///  not the current owner. Throws if `_to` is the zero address. Throws if
    ///  `_tokenId` is not a valid NFT. When transfer is complete, this function
    ///  checks if `_to` is a smart contract (code size > 0). If so, it calls
    ///  `onERC721Received` on `_to` and throws if the return value is not
    ///  `bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"))`
    /// @param _from The current owner of the NFT
    /// @param _to The new owner
    /// @param _tokenId The NFT to transfer
    /// @param data Additional data with no specified format, sent in call to `_to`
    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) public {
        transferFrom(_from, _to, _tokenId);

        //Get size of "_to" address, if 0 it's a wallet
        uint32 size;
        assembly {
            size := extcodesize(_to)
        }
        if(size > 0){
            ERC721TokenReceiver receiver = ERC721TokenReceiver(_to);
            require(receiver.onERC721Received(msg.sender,_from,_tokenId,data) == bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)")));
        }

    }

    /// @notice Transfers the ownership of an NFT from one address to another address
    /// @dev This works identically to the other function with an extra data parameter,
    ///  except this function just sets data to ""
    /// @param _from The current owner of the NFT
    /// @param _to The new owner
    /// @param _tokenId The NFT to transfer
    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external {
        safeTransferFrom(_from,_to,_tokenId,"");
    }


}
```

Here is my migration script:

```
var TokenERC721 = artifacts.require("../contracts/ERC721.sol");
var TokenERC721Enumerable = artifacts.require("../contracts/TokenERC721Enumerable");
var TokenERC721Metadata = artifacts.require("../contracts/TokenERC721Metadata");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TokenERC721, 2);
  deployer.deploy(TokenERC721Enumerable);
  deployer.deploy(TokenERC721Metadata);
};
```

Ganache is set to 10x max gas limit of mainnet (80M), and gas price is 1. I am putting in the uint value necessary in the constructor of TokenERC721, and I don't have any indexed bytes/strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `gas` amount as a part of the `deployer.deploy()` function calls like so:

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TokenERC721, 2, {gas: 6721975});
  deployer.deploy(TokenERC721Enumerable, {gas: 6721975});
  deployer.deploy(TokenERC721Metadata, {gas: 6721975});
};
```

This will define the amount of gas to be used on each of these transactions. You might need to modify the gas number based on your needs, but that should hopefully solve the root problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't included it in your question, the `TokenERC721Enumerable` and `TokenERC721Metadata` contracts both require constructor arguments.

The Enumerable one just takes an initial supply,

```
 constructor(uint _initialSupply) public TokenERC721(_initialSupply){...
```

But the Metadata one takes initial supply, name, symbol and uriBase,

```
constructor(uint _initialSupply, string _name, string _symbol, string _uriBase) public TokenERC721(_initialSupply){ ...
```

I'm not sure why this would be causing a gas error, so specifying the gas as in Shawn Tabrizi's answer may also help with that.